# Windows Phone 8 Camera hangs when not in Debug/Master mode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera, unity-game-engine

This is a problem that has been bugging me a lot. I still haven't got a solution for this.

I have this XAML code, the `DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid` is an Unity game, and the rest is collapsed Camera.

```
<DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid x:Name="DrawingSurfaceBackground" Loaded="DrawingSurfaceBackground_Loaded">

        <!-- Augmented Reality -->

        <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="arCameraStack" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Width="732" Height="549" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed" Tap="viewfinderCanvas_Tap">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush" />
            </Canvas.Background>
            <Image x:Name="imgTarget" Source="/Assets/Icons/camera.target.png"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="114" Canvas.Top="27"/>
        </Canvas>
</DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid>
```

These are my Start/Stop camera functions:

```
        public void StartCamera(bool hasTarget)
        {
            camera = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
            viewfinderBrush.SetSource(camera);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (hasTarget)
                {
                    imgTarget.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    imgTarget.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            });
        }

        public void StopCamera()
        {
            if (camera != null)
            {
                camera.Dispose();
                camera = null;
            }
        }
```

I have a screen system that changes the views according to what you want to see, sorta like changing pages.

This gets called in the page that shows the Camera part.

```
public void Show()
{
    MainPage.Instance.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        MainPage.Instance.arCameraStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    });
    MainPage.Instance.StartCamera(false);
}
```

And this gets called when I want to hide the Unity part.

```
    public void Hide()
    {
        UnityApp.SetNativeResolution(0, 0);
        UnityApp.Obscure(false);
        UnityApp.Deactivate();
        MainPage.Instance.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MainPage.Instance.ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
        });
    }
```

Everything works when I have the solution build and run through Visual Studio, but once I start the app from the phone, not in Master/Debug mode from VS, the camera just hangs. I found out that when I toggle the visibility of anything in the page, the camera will update for a second, and then hang once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out what was the problem.

My Show/Hide functions look like these now:

```
public void Hide()
    {

        UnityApp.Obscure(false);
        UnityApp.Deactivate();
        MainPage.Instance.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MainPage.Instance.DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundContentProvider(null);
            MainPage.Instance.DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundManipulationHandler(null);
            MainPage.Instance.HideUnityBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            MainPage.Instance.ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
        });
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        var content = Application.Current.Host.Content;
        var width = (int)Math.Floor(content.ActualWidth * content.ScaleFactor / 100.0 + 0.5);
        var height = (int)Math.Floor(content.ActualHeight * content.ScaleFactor / 100.0 + 0.5);
        UnityApp.SetNativeResolution(width, height);
        UnityApp.UnObscure();
        MainPage.Instance.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            MainPage.Instance.DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundContentProvider(UnityApp.GetBackgroundContentProvider());
            MainPage.Instance.DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundManipulationHandler(UnityApp.GetManipulationHandler());
            MainPage.Instance.HideUnityBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            MainPage.Instance.ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
        });
    }
```

The main problem was in the **DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundContentProvider** and **DrawingSurfaceBackground.SetBackgroundManiuplationHandler** functions.
Now switching between the Unity part and WP part is easy.